# Marker interfaces with different functionality distinguishing

Tags: java

How does one can distinguish the functionality if implemented marker interfaces like Serializable, Cloneable, Remote, EventListener ?

Example : class MarkerDemo implements Serializable, Cloneable, Remote, EvenListener

Comment: You should be able to use *instanceof* to distinguish if your instance is from a class that implements a given interface.

Answer (score 0):

Marker interface is meant to be used by a framework or library.  It can be discovered through api (for exmple, method accpeting `EventListener`) or through reflection with the library accpeting an `Object`. This feature became obsolete with the introduction of annotations in Java 5

Comment: I wouldn't say *obsolete*. A lot less necessary yes, and annotations give you more power. However annotations require more complex logic than a simple `instanceof` when using marker interfaces.

Comment: The reality is that there are little to no new Marker interfaces after Java 5. I believe had annotations existed before ,we would not even have `Serializable` and such

Comment: That's probably true. I wouldn't write new marker interfaces either.

Comment: Thanks Sharon Ben Asher and Kayaman for the response. I think answer will remain same for Marker interface but i have got the question other way round.